# How can I have the cart sidebar only show up when it's in checkout?

Tags: magento

I have modified the layout for checkout so the one-page checkout has a right-hand column and has the sidebar cart in it:

```
<checkout_onepage_index translate="label">
    <label>One Page Checkout</label>
    <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
    <remove name="left"/>
<update handle="page_two_columns_right" />
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="checkout_cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="root">…snip
```

I would like the sidebar to appear in the checkout even if it's disabled in other pages via the admin. Basically I just need a boolean value to insert in my overridden sidebar.phtml:

```
<?php if ($_someBooleanValue || $this->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()):?>
```

What's the best way to set the value of $_someBooleanValue to `true` when the block is within the checkout process, and `false` otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this. What I really needed was `getNameInLayout()` from `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract`. Since I control the layout xml I'm dealing with, I know what the name will be (*checkout_cart_sidebar* in this case), so I just needed to check if that was the name of the current block.

```
<?php if ($this->getNameInLayout() === 'checkout_cart_sidebar'
    || $this->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()):?>…snip
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use the local.xml file in the /app/design/frontend/yourtheme/yourskin/layout folder.  You can target specific pages to add/remove blocks from to override the base definitions.

Here's a good primer on the power of the local.xml file:

http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/5-useful-tricks-for-your-magento-local-xml/

Comment: But this approach makes the boolean method `getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()` have no meaning, as well as its associated Config setting. I would rather have the config setting continue to work for everything outside of the checkout.

Comment: True.  Glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 1):

You could get the page name and if the page name equals the page you want it to show up on then show the sidebar.

```
<?php
$currentFile = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
$parts = Explode('/', $currentFile);
$page = $parts[count($parts) - 1];
if($page == "checkoutpage.php")
{
  $_someBooleanValue = true;
}
?>
```

You could check if "checkout" is in the page name also.

```
<?php
$position = strpos($page, "checkout");
if($position == true){$_someBooleanValue = true;};

?>
```

However this is just a suggestion, but it may not be the best solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't want to depend on `PHP_SELF` for this value, but it's a clever approach!

Comment: No problem, I knew there were many other solutions but I felt this could be of help to your or someone who wanted to do something similar.